# How to show push notification in flutter without firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

In my flutter application, i have to show push notification without firebase. My server will send me a message after hitting a particular API, and that message i want to show as a push notification.

Can you show me a way how can i do it in flutter?

Comment: Push Notification NEEDS to work with FCM on Android and iOS with APN. If you want to display just a local notification, that's different. Push Notifications works for you to receive data when the app is closed, mostly.

Comment: How can i show local notification then? Right now can you tell me how can i show push notification simply if i got any message from server OR if i press any button on screen it shows me the push notification.

Comment: Check Navin's response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60110301/3743245

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Are we so dependent (on Flutter) on these 2 giants (Google/Apple) that we can not escape their gravitational force? Is there no implementation of push notification that can be truly open source and self-hosted?

Answer (score 9):

You can use Local notification plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

After your API response, just show that data in your local notification

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin(); // initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
    onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
```

Comment: does this work even when the app is not in focus or some other app is running live on screen?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: I use flutter_local_notifications for appointment reminders when my app is in the background and it works well.

Comment: And how do you get the app IDs?

Comment: This will not work on Android because the application on the background will go to IDLE status after a while. Check for foreground notifications to maintain the application up

Comment: There's no "push" here. This is just a solution to show local notifications, not remotely pushed ones.

Answer (score 2):

**There are two major ways to send push notifications to a flutter application without firebase.**

1. Using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package send to notification locally

example code:

```
    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('ypur-icon-name(icon)');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: _onNotificationClicked);
   }

   Future _showNotification() async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'Channel id', 'Your notification ID', 'Notification name',
    importance: Importance.defaultImportance,
    priority: Priority.defaultPriority);
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
     'Notification Alert ',
     'Message - There is a new notification on your account, kindly check it out',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload:
      'Message - There is a new notification on your account, kindly check it out',
     );
    }
   }
```

Then you create a function or just show a dialog when the notification is clicked
e.g

```
Future _onNotificationClicked() async {
  return showDialog();
);
```

And that for flutter local notification, you can check the package documentation for more info, another approach you can make use of is to connect this local notification to your database/server or API so it can be on call of your API that the user would receive the notification. etc

2. [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/): is a free push notification service for mobile apps. This SDK makes it easy to integrate your Flutter iOS and/or Android apps with OneSignal and it's also used in powering mobile + web push, email, SMS & in-app messages.

the package is available on pub.dev - [onesignal](https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter)

Answer (score 0):

it's not compatible with latest flutter version (null-safety) yet

Comment: Only 21 days later on May 22, 2021, it introduced null safety compatibility.