# flutter: how to get the push notification payload from non firebase source

Tags: flutter

I am getting push notification from  a non-firebase source. I see the push popup and when selected opens my app. However, I need get the payload from the message.

Firebase messaging handler only get me the payload from push message originate via firebase. Is there another plugin that will show me the message payload from non-firebase push.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to refer this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60108468/how-to-show-push-notification-in-flutter-without-firebase

Comment: Thanks, but this is sending a push from within the app.. I am getting a non-firebase push.. I see the push . just need to get the payload